# Why do user defined literal operators have to start with underscore?

Tags: c++, user-defined-literals

Since the Standard Library never defines literal operators in the root `std` namespace, what is the danger of having user defined operators *not* starting with underscore?

Comment: std adds and might continue to add UDL, reserving name avoid name clash.

Comment: @Jarod42 how would they clash if they are in a separate namespace?

Comment: They aren't in their own namespace when you use them.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica but this is already the case for string literal s and chrono literal s, they clash if you use them together, and you are forced to scope the use. How is this any different with user defined literals? Why cannot I have my own s and the only thing I can define is _s?

Comment: They can also add suffixes to the base language, don't forget that. C++23 Adds `5z` for size_t literals for example.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica thanks, I see it now, right what they did with the size literal in C++23.

Comment: @thebugger `s` from chrono and string do not clash since one applies for string literals other for numeric literals. https://godbolt.org/z/Msc1r6hE8

Comment: [std::string also defines operator""s, to represent literal objects of type std::string, but it is a string literal: 10s is ten seconds, but "10"s is a two-character string.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s)

Comment: Pretty ones(without leading underscore) are reserved for standard. Same reason for not using leading underscore for identifer names.